# How do I check where the symlink is pointing to in Ant

Tags: ant

Basically what I've asked in the title. How can I use the Ant "symlink" command to find out where the symlink is pointing to?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `symlink` task can only create and remove symlinks. You could execute something like `ls -la ${file} | awk '{print $10}'` and capture the output with a redirector but this looks like an ugly hack - there should be a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the Reploy Jakob. I think the solution as you said, is outside the realm of Ant.